# Required input is not working?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this input but its not working because i have in name []. Any suggestion how can i fix this? If i remove this `[{{$language->code}}]` required is working.

```
    @foreach ($languages as $language)
          <input type="text" id="text-title" name="article_title[{{$language->code}}]" value="" class="form_input" required="required">
    @endforeach

 <button type="submit" class="submit_property bg_green pull-right">CREATE ARTICLE</button>
```

validation rules:

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'article_title'                 => 'required:articles',
            'slug'                          => 'required|unique:articles',
    }
```

Problem is that i need required rule only if `$language->id = 1`

Comment: What is your validation rule?

Comment: @mrabbani i edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Laravel's native validation of array:

`$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'article_title.*' => 'required',
]);`

Comment: problem with that is that i need required only if language->id = 1 . Is that possible with laravel validation?

Comment: Yes you can: you can create rules array like this: `$rules = [];` and check if
language id = 1 than: `$rules['article_title'] => 'required';` and than validate the request.

Comment: if($default_language){
         $rules['article_title'] => 'required';
        } i get an error here syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)

Comment: Sorry for my mistaken answer up there. There must be `if($default_language){ $rules['article_title'] = 'required'; } `

Comment: now i get this error: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make() must be of the type array, null given,

Comment: do you have any other validation rules?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132445/discussion-between-none-and-buglinjo).

Answer (score 0):

The rule will be

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'article_title.*' => 'required',
        'slug'            => 'required|unique:articles',
    ];

}
```